# Repeat tab containing dynamic components within an apex:tabpanel

Tags: dynamic-visualforce, tab

Suppose we have n tabs within a tab panel in a visualforce page. All of the tabs contain the same markup, but their content is dynamic. So far the only way we have found to build this is to copy and paste the markup into the n separate tabs. We would like to stay away from using components because of data routing between the component controllers and the page controller. We also want to stay native here, and do not want to build out a custom tab interface (ie. HTML, CSS, JavaScript).

Does anyone have suggestions for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are not many options: `apex:composition`, `apex:include` or just an `apex:iframe`.

Comment: Developers and ISVs please vote for this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kteEAAQ